# Upgrading and old ffmpeg version to the latest on redhat

Tags: installation, ffmpeg, make, redhat-enterprise-linux

Currently I'm on a new project and working with an existing server (redhat) that has already been setup. One of my tasks right now is to upgrade ffmpeg to the latest version. I'm familiar with navigating the shell and all, but I'm not too familiar with how to upgrade software. So far I have the following down:

- Typing the ffmpeg command I can get the version number (2.6402)
- Doing a *which ffmpeg* shows me that the command is being run from (/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg)

[image]

I then download the new updated release from: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases -- And I read the Install.md file:

[image]

- I'm afraid to type the install commands as I don't want to overwrite my existing ffmpeg version as I didn't back it up in case if it doesnt work well. Or does the ./compile and make install only happen in the current directory only?
- How do I backup my existing ffmpeg in case I need to revert it back?

Comment: Show the output of `uname -a`. This info is required because the available static builds of ffmpeg won't work if your kernel is ancient. Next time please simply copy and paste text instead of making screenshots of text.

Comment: Linux YRNYEELX05 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 29 10:16:43 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [download an already compiled `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

To use it you have several options:

- Navigate to the directory that contains the binary file and run `./ffmpeg`.
- Or provide the full path to the binary such as `~/Downloads/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg`
- Or move the binary into a directory listed in your PATH environmental variable, such as `/usr/local/bin`. Refer to `echo $PATH`.
- Or make a `bin` directory in your home directory and move the `ffmpeg` file into it (`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` is likely included in your `~/.bash_profile` file).